# "Between each" and Other Constructions with Fewer than Two Objects

Tags: prepositions, grammatical-number, determiners, logic

Page 112 of Garner's fourth edition reads

***✳Between each* and Other Constructions with Fewer than Two Objects**

> This phrasing is a peculiar brand of illogic, *✳between each
> house/speech*,instead of, properly, *between speeches* and *between every two houses*
> (native speakers of English don’t consciously think
> of the phrase as *between each house and the next*).

However I don't fully grasp its point.

Does *between each house and the next* mean the same as "between houses"?

Why don't native speakers consciously think of it as such?

Comment: Elsewhere, Garner's reads "**Between** calls for a plural or compound object, but it's standard when more than one is meant: _Spread butter between each layer_".

Comment: 'There is a thick hedge between each house' is grammatical even though it looks an illogical usage. Very few native speakers would even dream of adding the logically required 'and the next' /  'and its neighbour'. So the illogical deleted version is not only acceptable, it is the idiomatic choice.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Does between each house and the next mean the same as "between houses"? Why does the author use different syntax for _houses_ and _speeches_?

Comment: There is an established pattern with events: 'between speeches / matches / innings / acts ...' are idiomatic. The anarthrous string is less idiomatic with the spatial usage of 'between' referring to physical entities (? 'between mountains / clouds / towns / gardens / houses / people [one man and the next] ...').